# MySQL Trigger "syntax error, unexpected END, expecting ';'"

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger to validate an email address in a customer table, but am getting the error

> syntax error, unexpected END, expecting ';'

My code is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_validation_email
 BEFORE INSERT ON customer FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.CustomerEmail NOT REGEXP '^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]{2,}$')
        THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: invalid email address'
    END* IF
END
```

END* is where it is underlined with the error (the asterisk is not there)

There are other validation triggers which will be included, so the begin and end statement is needed

Comment: Have you re-set the delimiter?

Comment: `END*`? There is also no `;` after the `if` block or the final `END`.

Comment: The asterisk is just there to identify where the error is, it's not actually in my code. 

Adding a ';' at the end of the if block produces and additional error "syntax error, unexpected END_OF_INPUT, expecting ';'"

Comment: Fixed by changing delimiter to $$, thanks Gordon

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing delimiter and putting ; after if block and final END. Thanks Gordon Linoff and a_horse_with_no_name for helping

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_email
     BEFORE INSERT ON customer FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF (NEW.CustomerEmail NOT REGEXP '^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]{2,}$')
            THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: invalid email address';
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```